# Add a watermark overlayed to floats (figures, tables ... but mostly tables)

Tags: tables, floats, watermark

I would like to put a watermark, e.g. "DRAFT", but only *overlayed* and on *specific* figures and tables.

Looking around, I tried to use the `background` package. At the beginning of my document:

```
\usepackage[some]{background}
\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgContents{\parbox{10cm}{%
  \Huge Draft:  \today\\[14cm]\rotatebox{180}{\Huge Draft:  \today}}}
\SetBgColor{gray}
\SetBgAngle{270}
\SetBgOpacity{0.2}
```

Then inside the `table` environment:

```
\begin{table}
\BgThispage
\small
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}
[...]
```

The result is however that the watermark appears one page before the table, not on the same page. I tried adding the `[H]` option to the table, hoping to force LaTeX but to no avail.

Then I tried using the `xwatermark` package. While not optimal, it gives me an option to apply a watermark on specific pages:

```
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\newwatermark[pagex={178,179},fontfamily=bch,color=gray!25,angle=45,scale=3,12xpos=0,ypos=0]{DRAFT}
```

However when I compile with PDFLatex, XeLatex or LuaLatex:

```
 ! Package ltxkeys Error: The above keys are undefined and couldn't be set.
```

A workaround I have for figures is to open them in Inkscape and directly write my watermark on top of it. But I don't have this option for the table.

Do you have a solution? Thanks!

Comment: don't use xwatermark, it is not compatible with a current latex. Which LaTeX version do you use?

Comment: This is the output of `latex --version` : `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian)`
Alright so xwatermark is out of question I guess. Any alternative?

Comment: well xwatermark will still work there, but it will break if you update your latex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Too big for a comment)

`\tikzmark{}`s inside the floats shows promise:

[image: tikzfloat]

Someone more knowledgeable in TikZ might be able to help.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
x
\newpage
xx 

\begin{figure}
\tikzmark{tmTL}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
\tikzmark{tmBR}
\end{center}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:eg}
\end{figure}

Some text

\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\hline \\
\tikzmark{ttmTL} xxx & xxx & xxx \\
xxx & xxx & xxx \\
xxx & xxx & xxx\tikzmark{ttmBR}  \\
\hline \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:eg}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\tikz[overlay,remember picture]\draw[->,red,thick] (pic cs:tmTL) to [edge label={\huge DRAFT}] (pic cs:tmBR) ;

\tikz[overlay,remember picture]\draw[->,red,thick,] (pic cs:ttmTL) to [edge label={\huge DRAFT}]  (pic cs:ttmBR) ;
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! However I didn't manage to get it work. Depending on where I put the "tizkmark", the overlay was either on the wrong page, or below the table out of the page. Not exactly sure why - my table is about the size of one page (can't show it because it contains data that I don't want to be public).
Same for a figure: Putting the tikzmark at the same place as you, the "DRAFT" text appeared two pages below the figure.

Comment: Create a dummy table; no need to use actual info. Multiple compilations will be needed as floats and positions "settle".

Comment: Here's an example: [imgur link, two screenshots](https://imgur.com/a/RCFkVz5). The watermark appears on the following page of the table. Compiled 5 times with PDFLatex. If I remove the `[H]` option, the watermark appears on the _previous_ page (five compilations again). If I change the tikzmark to be within the table cells, no watermark appears at all :'(

Comment: Ah, WAIT. I actually managed to make it work, but it needs the tabular to be within the document instead of in a separate document. Ok, now to explore Tikz options to make it appear the way I'd like. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This uses `lrbox` and `varwidth` to measure the size of the contents, `\llap` to overlay it, and `\resizebox` to scale the overlaid image.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}% for \resizebox
\usepackage{varwidth}

\newsavebox{\draftbox}
\savebox{\draftbox}{\color{red}\huge Draft}% create image for overlay

\newenvironment{draft}{\begin{lrbox}{0}\varwidth[b]{\linewidth}}%
  {\endvarwidth\end{lrbox}\usebox0
  \llap{\resizebox{\wd0}{\ht0}{\usebox\draftbox}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{draft}
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:eg}
\end{draft}
\end{figure}

Some text

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{draft}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\hline \\
xxx & xxx & xxx \\
xxx & xxx & xxx \\
xxx & xxx & xxx \\
\hline \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:eg}
\end{draft}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

This version uses the entire width and puts the overlay into the background.  Note that `\centering` is now inside `draft`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}% for \resizebox

\newsavebox{\draftbox}
\savebox{\draftbox}{\color{red}\huge Draft}% create image for overlay

\newenvironment{draft}{\begin{lrbox}{0}\minipage[b]{\linewidth}}%
  {\endminipage\end{lrbox}%
  \leavevmode\rlap{\resizebox{\wd0}{\ht0}{\usebox\draftbox}}\usebox0}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{draft}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:eg}
\end{draft}
\end{figure}

Some text

\begin{table}
\begin{draft}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\hline \\
xxx & xxx & xxx \\
xxx & xxx & xxx \\
xxx & xxx & xxx \\
\hline \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:eg}
\end{draft}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! In these two solutions, is there a way to e.g. rotate the text?

Comment: \rotatebox from adjustbox, but do it inside the \resizebox, or possibly inside the original \savebox.  You can also use an image file for the overlay.